# Azure Blob Storage get exception AuthorizationPermissionMismatch when posting blob with tags

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure.Storage.Blobs libraries in a .NET app. When I use this code to upload a Blob

```
string fileName = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff}.json";
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
var options = new BlobUploadOptions
  {
    Tags = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
      { "Status", isFailed ? "Failed" : "Success" },
      { "DeviceId", queueItem.DeviceId.ToString() },
    }
};
var blobClient = _blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(BinaryData.FromString(json), options);
//await _blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, BinaryData.FromString(json));
```

I get this exception:

```
    Result: Failure Exception: Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. 
    RequestId:21a733b3-201e-00a4-7899-75df76000000 Time:2024-03-13T22:57:46.6502306Z Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.) 
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch Content: ﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

But if I use the commented out code above, i.e. post the blob without tags, it works fine.

This is running in an Azure FunctionApp and I have given the service principal the role "Storage Blob Data Contributor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" does not have the correct permission to upload blobs with tags.

You may either grant the principal "Storage Blob Data Owner" or create a custom role and add the correct permission for the `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/tags/write` Azure resource provider operation

Reference: [Upload a new blob with index tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=azure-portal#upload-a-new-blob-with-index-tags)

> This task can be performed by a Storage Blob Data Owner or a security principal that has been given permission to the Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/tags/write Azure resource provider operation via a custom Azure role.

Comment: Thanks, adding the Data Owner role solved it.